# Soundcloud API - What is the status of user-playback-count?

Tags: soundcloud

I tried to make use of the `user-playback-count` property of the [`/tracks`](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) resource (well actually `users/{id}/tracks`). It never returned anything over `1`. After some searching I came across this [2 years old post](https://groups.google.com/group/soundcloudapi/msg/03c62b45e49db2e8?dmode=source) which explains. I did not find any other information though, which led me to the question:

What is the status and prospect of the `user-playback-count` property?

*The Soundcloud team [encourages](http://developers.soundcloud.com/support) people to address them through SO.*

Comment: Then hopefully the Soundcloud team will be available here to answer your question, and aren't just crowd-sourcing their technical support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property was deprecated. Sorry for the lack of documentation on this one.